# Разница между методами стандартной библиотеки и самодельными методами

Tags: java

Есть метод System.arraycopy(), и так же можно сделать подобный метод, к примеру

```
int[] arrOne = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] arrTwo;
arrTwo = new int[arrOne.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++){
  arrTwo[i] = arrOne[i];
}
```

и подобных методов много, и вот интересует вопрос, какой метод будет выгодней использовать в плане быстродействия. а то бывает пишешь пишешь метод, а узнаешь об его существовании подобного позже.
 Так же к примеру с регулярными выражениями, Мне нужно проверить строку, и Я буду писать метод с минимумом данных, в то время как класс java.util.regex довольно тяжелый. 
Конечно понятно что код будет громоздким, ну или сам проект с "лишними" классами, но все таки интересует быстродействие.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: всё зависит от ваших навыков. Методы написанные _специально_ под задачу работают в предельной оптимизации _не медленнее_ чем общие методы.

Comment: Конечно всего не знаю, но вдруг к примеру некоторые общие методы могут работать быстрее, потому что там к примеру идёт работа на прямую с регистрами.(конечно мог и ахинею написать, если что извините за нубство :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, методы стандартной библиотеки написали и много лет подряд "полируют" программисты экстра-класса. В мире очень мало программистов, способных написать версию лучше. Во-вторых, в стандартной библиотеке немало [intrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function)-методов, использующих платформозависимую сишную реализацию, зашитую в JVM. К ним, кстати, относится и [System.arraycopy()](https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc#file-hotspot-jvm-intrinsics-L47). Наконец, использование классов из пакета `java.util.regex` не сделает вашу программу "тяжелее".

Comment: Во. спасибо, выдали то, что так хотел услышать :). Интринсик  тоже не разу такое не слышал, но как прочитал всё стало понятно, так что спасибо за ответ.

Comment: и да и нет. Поиск подстроки в строке там например написан банальным квадратичным алгоритмом и так далее. Т.е. если вы _знаете_ что делаете - переписывайте смело.

Comment: @pavel а Шипилёв говорит, что String.indexOf - это intrinsic использующий SIMD-инструкции, а потому резок чрезвычайно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот простой тест я сделал) https://ideone.com/Fxbi9e хотя кмп надо менее секунды.